# Issue with simultaneous development & testing - SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

There is a server where both development & testing is going on simultaneously. Now SIT team has raised 5 issues. Development team has fix 1 issue & want to redeploy that functionality. If we deploy code sit team cannot test at that time. Now question is how to overcome this situation so that both redeployment of code & testing by SIT team can run simultaneously? What is the way-out?

let's say this is a hypothetical situation & developer is redeploying the dll, but main question is how both can happens together?

Comment: any idea on this?

Comment: Why can't the "SIT" team test when you deploy your code? Usually a deployment forces an app pool recycle which causes a short interruption, but that should not be a big deal.

Comment: any other reply?

Comment: is this a good practice to test & do development in the same server by different members? plz reply.

Comment: Best practice is to have each developer running a SharePoint environment of their own. This is usually accomplished by installing a standalone SharePoint environment in a virtual environment such as Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect deploy code and test *at the same time*.

Two options come to mind:

1. Deploy the new code during an agreed upon maintenance window. You can use the same server but you will need to communicate with the team doing the testing and let them know they can't test during this time.
2. Get another server purely for testing. IMO, this is the better option because then you can do development at the same time the other team is testing without interrupting each other.